# How to pass an object from android app to a firebase cloud function to complete Paypal payment functions?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, paypal, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase cloud functions as serverside for Paypal payment. Documentations are not obvious to understand. 
when I am trying to send an object from android app to firebase cloud functions, nothing has happened. I think I added it wrong. so how can I pass an object from android app to the function??

```
  public  void  payout(String PayerID,String paymentId) {
    // Create the arguments to the callable function.
    JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();
    try {
        postData.put("PayerID", PayerID);
        postData.put("paymentId",paymentId);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     mFunctions
            .getHttpsCallable("payout")
            .call(postData)
            .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) 
    throws Exception {
                    return null;
                }
            });
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

```
 exports.payout=functions.https.onRequest((req,res)=>{

const sender_batch_id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(9);
const payReq=JSON.stringify({
        sender_batch_header: {
            sender_batch_id: sender_batch_id,
            email_subject: "You have a nice  payment"
        },
        items: [
            {
                recipient_type: "EMAIL",
                amount: {
                    value: 0.90,
                    currency: "USD"
                },
                receiver: "amrmahmoudM@app.com",
                note: "Thank you very much.",
                sender_item_id: "item_3"
            }
        ]
});
paypal.payout.create(payReq,(error, payout)=>{
    if (error) {
        console.warn(error.res);
        res.status('500').end();
        throw error;

    }else{
        console.info("payout created");
        console.info(payout);
        res.status('200').end();

    }
});
   });
  exports.process = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
const paymentId = req.body.paymentId;
var payerId = {
  payer_id: req.body.PayerID
};
return paypal.payout.execute(paymentId, payerId, (error, payout) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    if (payout.state === 'approved') {
      console.info('payment completed successfully, description: ', 
        payout.transactions[0].description);
      const ref=admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(payerId);
       ref.set({'paid': true});


    } else {
      console.warn('payment.state: not approved ?');
              }
  }
}).then(r =>
     console.info('promise: ', r));
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that in your Android app you call an HTTPS Callable Function (via `mFunctions.getHttpsCallable("payout")`) but your Cloud Function is not an HTTPS Callable Function but a "simple" HTTPS Function.

HTTPS Callable Functions are written like:

```
exports.payout = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // ...
});
```

while HTTPS Functions are written like:

```
exports.payout = functions.https.onRequest((req,res)=> {
  // ...
})
```

So you should adapt the code of your Cloud Function according to the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

---

Note that another option could be to write to the database (Real Time database or Firestore) and trigger the Cloud Function with an `onWrite` or `onCreate` trigger. The advantage of this approach is that you directly save the information of the payment in the database.

Comment: but the documentation suggests using HTTP requests, not the firstore or real-time triggers .. see this link it has the docs for PayPal integration https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/paypal/functions/index.js

Comment: Yes this sample uses HTTPS Function, but this is just the trigger for executing the code. So you can very well use any other Cloud Functions trigger, in particular an HTTPS Callable Function trigger or a background trigger. You just have to slightly adapt the code to read the data you are getting from the front end.

Comment: does this rule generalized? even for paypal integration?

Comment: Your last question is actually too broad to answer it correctly. You should choose your Cloud Function trigger depending on your requirements. But what is sure is that with different triggers you can run the same business logic within a Cloud Function. And it is the case for a payment where the only constraint is the fact that the payment platform is called by a managed environment (i.e. the Cloud Functions service in this case).